# Errors when trying to create a new React app

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm trying to create a React app but get errors when I do so

```
create-react-app eth-todo-list-react

Creating a new React app in C:\Users\Aristophanes\eth-todo-list-react.

'yarnpkg' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts...

'yarnpkg' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
events.js:167
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn yarnpkg ENOENT
    at notFoundError (C:\Users\Aristophanes\node_modules\create-react-app\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:6:26)
    at verifyENOENT (C:\Users\Aristophanes\node_modules\create-react-app\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:40:16)
    at ChildProcess.cp.emit (C:\Users\Aristophanes\node_modules\create-react-app\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:27:25)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:246:12)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at ChildProcess.cp.emit (C:\Users\Aristophanes\node_modules\create-react-app\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:30:37)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:246:12)
```

it should say "success" and initialize a git depository. But I get the errors above instead.

Comment: Possibly relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49281952/error-while-using-create-react-app-enoent You could try the troubleshooting listed there.

Comment: also possible solution: https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/2504

Comment: Neither of these methods fix anything. I've changed the path as instructed. I get the same errors.