# Can't create a new React app - ENOENT error appears

Tags: node.js, reactjs

This is what I get when trying to run `npx create-react-app my-app`

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn C:\Program Files\git\bin\bash.exe
npm ERR! path C:\Users\me\Desktop\ReactProjects
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent spawn C:\Program Files\git\bin\bash.exe ENOENT
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
```

Comment: Do you have Git installed?

Comment: Yes, I have git installed on my pc

Comment: can you get the Node version when you are in you project directory?

Comment: this looks similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49281952/error-while-using-create-react-app-enoent