Error while running npx create-react-app my-app on VS Code
Have installed Node.js and VS Code too. While running npx create-react-app my-app in the terminal there is the error coming:
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall lstat
npm ERR! path C:\Users\AMAN\AppData\Roaming\npm
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'C:\Users\AMAN\AppData\Roaming\npm'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\AMAN\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-04-06T15_41_19_323Z-debug-0.log

I don't know what to do. I tried npm cache clean --force but after that, this came npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled. Also tried package-lock.json but no use.

Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49281952/error-while-using-create-react-app-enoent

create-react-app is deprecated and you should have no expectation it should continue to work.
